# Can I change allow_mult to false on map bucket/bucket type in riak?

Tags: riak, bucket

How can I change the allow_mult property to false on map data type bucket or bucket type?

I tried this but not working.

> #### >riak-admin bucket-type update maps '{"props":{"allow_mult":false}}'
>
> Error updating bucket type maps: Cannot change datatype bucket from
> allow_mult=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to turn allow_mult to false ? I think it's needed for the map data type to work properly. Values stored in it will properly automatically converge by themselves, so you'll never see siblings from the client point of view, but I suspect CRDTs need allow_mult to be true.